# Iterator<T> returns Object

Tags: java, generics, iterator

i wrote simple class:

```java
public class Report<T> implements Iterable {
  private ObservableList<T> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  // ...

  public ObservableList<T> getItems() {
    return items;
  }

  public Iterator<T> iterator {
    return items.iterator();
  }

  //  ...
}
```

But when i try to use foreach loop like this i get Incompatible types error:

```java
Report<FinRecord> report = new Report<>()
for (FinRecord r : report) {
    // ...
}
```

This code works fine, but i wanted cleaner code and i don't understand why previous code returns Object.

```java
for (FinRecord r : report.getItems()) {
    // ...
}
```

Is it java's peculiarity, so it creates `Iterator` not `Iterator<T>` or i am missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your class has to `implements Iterable<T>`.

```
public class Report<T> implements Iterable<T>
{
  private ObservableList<T> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  // ...

  public ObservableList<T> getItems() {
    return items;
  }

  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return items.iterator();
  }

  //  ...
}
```